# Gray Palette representing Scatter Plot with Gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, scatter-plot, grayscale

I have some Scatter Plots of Number of Citations vs Year of Publication

[image]

This one corresponds to a famous german physicist ..

The command that I use for plotting that graph is:

```
gnuplot -e "set title 'Citations vs Publication Year'; set xlabel 'Publication Year'; set ylabel 'Citations'; set terminal png size 800,600; set output 'citations.png'; plot 'plotting_data.txt' with points pt 7 lc rgb 'red'; pause -1"
```

Is it possible to make a plot like a Gray Palette where the black bands represent the dots with higher citations and the white bands represent the dots with lower citations .. I guess one band my represent 1 year .. In the case there are multiple publications that year, I guess it can be taken the publication with the highest number of citations ..

[image]

For example, in the german physicist example, the band corresponding to 1905 is going to be very black, in the band of 1910 is going to be gray .. etc ..

Answer (score 3):

```
set palette gray negative
set cbrange [0:*]
plot 'plotting_data.txt' using 1:2:2 with points pt 7 lc palette
```